# Is there any current scientific project to test length contraction experimentally or the door is closed about possibility of this kind of experiments?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, speed-of-light

Special relativity shows that moving frames are contracted along its motion and time is dilated, we prove time dilation experimentally but length contraction still away from testing, there are many difficulties to test phenomenon of length contraction but I would like to ask about predictions to find a method or novel genius idea enable us to test length contraction directly

Comment: Length contraction, time dilation it's a question of frame of reference.  Take the classic observation of muons generated in the upper atmosphere.  In their frame of reference, reaching the earth depends on length contraction.

Comment: I strongly dislike the implication in the question's title that special relativity is treated as dogma and that physical science has "closed the door" to the consideration of experimental testing. There is a [mountain of evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_special_relativity) that supports special relativity, including [multiple tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction#Experimental_verifications) that involve length contraction. If that wasn't what you meant to imply, then you should edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty - it is a perfectly reasonable question. There are many experimental validations of relativistic time and mass variation but I can't think of a direct length experiment - except redshifted photons , unless you consider that a time effect

Comment: @MartinBeckett The question is indeed passable, which is why I didn't vote to close, but the language it uses is extremely problematic. (And, that said: the difference between length contraction and time dilation is frame-dependent, as both can be required to explain a given observation depending on what frame is used for analysis. M. Enns' comment is a clear example of that.)

Comment: The question contains a false dichotomy. As @M.Enns and Emilio Pisanty point out, length contraction and time dilation are the same thing.  So if you prove one, you prove the other. The *door closed* expression comes across as slightly pejorative, which is what is raising some hackles...

Answer (score 1):

Length contraction is harder to measure than time dilation and [cannot be measured in the rest frame of the object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trouton%E2%80%93Rankine_experiment), but there are a few effects that allows checking the predictions of SR:

- Presumably the best nontrivial evidence is heavy ion collisions where
  length contraction means the nuclei and electric fields look like
  pancakes when passing each other. This has observable effects on the
  cross sections and energy densities, and fits well with models
  (Bjorken, Landau) of relativistic hydrodynamics.
- The flattening of the fields also affects ionization properties.
- [When designing free-electron lasers](http://flash.desy.de/sites2009/site_vuvfel/content/e395/e2188/FLASH-Broschrefrs_web.pdf) length contraction has to be
  included for them to work.
- Apparently [magnetic vortices in Josephson junctions](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.75.1372) have been
  observed to have length contraction.
- One can argue that the the Michelson-Morley experiment is the
  simplest and earliest demonstration: the arms are length contracted
  in such a way that one gets the famous null result.

Of course, in SR time and space dilation/contraction effects will always be hard to separate: they are rarely "pure".